# Is it possible to use Moodle database for authentication to sign in another system?

Tags: php, database, moodle

We have a system (little) and we need to use authentication to login in to the system. And also we have moodle system is running. My question is that, can we use moodle user creditentials to login to our system ?

Comment: Is this system that you have is another seperate management system or custom made system?

Comment: @Yousuf Tafhim, Custom made system

Comment: Yes, it is possible but not recommended. As Moodle can get updated anytime and your other systems will depend on it. So when you upgrade moodle things may not work your way. You can create an independent auth service with single sign on (sso) feature. 

You can also check some ready solutions explained in the moodle documentation.

https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/Authentication
https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/OAuth_2_services#OAuth2_services